# Decomposition of a function/measure into a continuous and discontinuous function/measure.

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

I'm reading a book where the author states

> In Chapter 1 we have seen that, to every increasing function α(t)
> defined on [0, ∞[, there corresponds a measure dα(t). In the
> terminology of measure theory, α is continuous if and only if dα is a
> diffuse measure (that is, the support of dα has no atoms). If dα is
> purely atomic (that is, the support of dα consists of a countable
> number of atoms), then α is said to be purely discontinuous. Every
> σ-finite measure on [0, ∞[ can be written in a unique way as the sum
> of a diffuse and a purely atomic measure. This corresponds to the
> unique decomposition of an increasing function into the sum of a
> continuous and purely discontinuous function.

In Chapter 1 of that book, the only decomposition theorem that was alluded to was the Lebesgue decomposition theorem.

How, from that theorem, do we get «Every σ-finite measure on [0, ∞[ can be written in a unique way as the sum of a diffuse and a purely atomic measure. This corresponds to the unique decomposition of an increasing function into the sum of a continuous and purely discontinuous function.» ? In the theorem, the decomposition is with respect to a second different measure. There's no reference to it in this sentence, or in the paragraph above...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you have to prove that a $\sigma-$finite measure on $\mathbb{R}^+$ has only points for atoms (this also depends on the definition you have of atom, the one I am using here is: a set $A$ such that $B\subsetneq A$, $B$ measurable implies $\mu(B)\in\{0,\mu(A)\}$). This is a nice exercise but if you need I can be more explicit.

Now that we have this result, let $S=\{x\in\mathbb{R}^+:d\alpha(\{x\})>0\}$. This set must be countable. One proves this result with a standard trick: suppose that $S$ is uncountable. Then, since $d\alpha$ is $\sigma-$finite, $\mathbb{R}^+=\cup B_n$ with $\mu(B_n)<+\infty$. Since $S=\cup_n (S\cap B_n)$, there must be a $j:$ $T:=S\cap B_j$ is uncountable (actually, it suffices for $d\alpha$ to be semi-finite but this is not relevant here). Now, let $T_n=\{x\in T:d\alpha(x)>\frac1n\}$. Since $T=\cup T_n$ and $T$ is uncountable, there must be a $k:T_k$ is uncountable. Let $\{x_1,\dots,x_n,\dots,\}$ be a countable sequence in $T_k$. This implies $d\alpha(B_j)\ge \sum d\alpha(x_l)\ge \frac{1}{k}\sum_l 1=+\infty$, absurd.

Since $S$ must be countable, let $\mu:=d\alpha_{|S}$ and $\nu=d\alpha-\mu$. Can you see how $\mu$ is purely discontinuous and $\nu$ is diffuse?

Comment: Hi Pelota, sorry for the tardiness, but life happened. Thanks for your answer! I have 2 doubts: 1) Couldn't we, using the same reasoning, prove that S must be finite? 2)Do you have a bibliography that you would recommend for stochastic calculus?

Comment: Hy @Anoldmaninthesea. It is my turn to apologize for the tardiness :). Regarding $1)$: we cannot. A central point in the trick is that the countable union of countable sets is countable, while the similar statement for finite sets (countable union of finite sets is finite) is false. For example, let $\mu(A):=\#\{A\cap \mathbb{N}\}$: this is a $\sigma-$finite measure with infinite support $S=\mathbb{N}$. For $2)$: that is not my field so I cannot be helpful unfortunately.

Comment: Many thanks! ;)